# I want to implment pusher in my android app, but when I send event it's return lib is deprecated, please anybody help me to get out of this exception

Tags: android

I want to implement pusher in my android application, but when I send event it's return lib is deprecated, please anybody help me to get out of this exception. Is there any working libs for pusher then please provide?

Comment: Thanks for your replay...

Pusher is a simple hosted API for quickly, easily and securely integrating realtime bi-directional functionality via WebSockets to web and mobile apps, or any other Internet connected device.

https://app.pusher.com/

Comment: You need to provide details of your manifest file and libs folder with versions.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pusher/pusher-android-example - Sample app 0.0.1 library. I'm running 0.3.3.
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/pusher/pusher-java-client/
This is the download server for the java clients.
Hope this helped :)